# How to add a js file to html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is 3 files, which is called a.html, a.css, and a.js.

```
<a href="#">Parks and Recreation</a>
            <a href="#">Children's Hospital</a>
            <a href="#">Downton Abbey</a>
            <a href="#">Madmen</a>
            <a href="#">30 Rock</a>
```

The buttons do not light up when the cursor is aligned. Please help. Sorry I am too much of a beginner. I've tried a few things, but...

```js
function on_resize(c,t){onresize=function(){clearTimeout(t);t=setTimeout(c,100)};return c};

$('#more').hide();
on_resize( function() {
  var navSpace = $('#links').outerWidth();
   
  var linksWidth = 0;
  $('#links > a').each(function() {
    linksWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
  });

  if( linksWidth > Space ) {
    while( linksWidth > navSpace ) {
      var lastLink = $('#links > a:last');
      var lastLinkWidth = lastLink.outerWidth();
      $(lastLink).data( 'foo', lastLinkWidth );  
      $('#overflow').prepend(lastLink); 
      linksWidth = linksWidth - lastLinkWidth;
    }
    $('#more').show();
    $('#more-label').text( $('#overflow > a').length + ' More...' );
  }else{
    while( linksWidth <= navSpace ) {
      var firstOverflowLink = $('#overflow > a:first');
      var firstOverflowLinkWidth = firstOverflowLink.data('foo');
      if( navSpace - linksWidth > firstOverflowLinkWidth ) {
        $('#links').append(firstOverflowLink);
      }
      linksWidth = linksWidth + firstOverflowLinkWidth;
    }
    $('#more-label').text($('#overflow > a').length+' More...');
    if( $('#overflow > a').length == 0 ){
      $('#more').hide();
    }
  } 
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

body{
  min-width: 300px;
  font-family: Futura, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#nav{
  background: black;
  padding-right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#links{
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}

#links a{
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #aaa;
  &:hover,
  &:focus{
    color: white;
  }
}

#more{
    background: #333;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}


#overflow{
  display: none;
  background: #222;
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  a{
    color: #aaa;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    &:hover,
    &:focus{
      color: white;
    }
  }
}

#more:hover{
  #overflow{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="a.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="links">
        <a href="#">Parks and Recreation</a>
        <a href="#">Children's Hospital</a>
        <a href="#">Downton Abbey</a>
        <a href="#">Madmen</a>
        <a href="#">30 Rock</a>
      </div>
      <div id="more">
        <span id="more-label">More</span>
        <div id="overflow"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="debug"></div>
    <div id="debug2"></div>
    <div id="debug3"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

this error message about these codes. I have no idea about that. I guess my html is wrong...
{
"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
"filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 118,
"colno": 1
}

Comment: I think you are not loading JQuery. Check JQuery documentation how to "install" it.

Comment: Is your `$` from jQuery? If yes, make sure that jQuery is loaded and try to use `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();`.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. 1. How could I load jQuery? 2. Could I code it without using library like jQuery, react, and vue etc?

Comment: Read more about [download jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/). You can code without jQuery or those things.